# Pause Setinterval if window blur

Tags: ajax, focus, setinterval, blur

i ve found a code here to help find if a tab is active. The objective is to call an ajax (cross domain) url every ten seconds in order to find how long does a user stays on a website.
After finding different adaptations i m calling here for help ! Thanks in advance for any explanations :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var state='';

(function() {
    var hidden, change, vis = {
            hidden: "visibilitychange",
            mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
            webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
            msHidden: "msvisibilitychange",
            oHidden: "ovisibilitychange" /* not currently supported */
        };             
    for (hidden in vis) {
        if (vis.hasOwnProperty(hidden) && hidden in document) {
            change = vis[hidden];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (change)//this is for detecting without  focus, so it works for your second requirement
        document.addEventListener(change, onchange);
    else if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) // IE 9 and lower
        document.onfocusin = document.onfocusout = onchange
    else
        window.onfocus = window.onblur = onchange;

    function onchange (evt) {
        var body = document.body;
        evt = evt || window.event;

        if (evt.type == "focus" || evt.type == "focusin")
       {   
    body.className = "visible";
       state='visible';
        }         else if (evt.type == "blur" || evt.type == "focusout")
        {  body.className = "hidden";     state='';}
            else    {    
            body.className = this[hidden] ? "hidden" : "visible";}
    }

})();

setInterval(function() {
if(state=='visible')
{
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
     }
  }
request.open('GET', 'http://mywebsite.com.php?v=<?php echo $idvisite;?>', true);
request.send();
}
}, 10000);

</script>
```

Comment: what is your specific problem? can you isolate it?

Comment: My problem is that nothing the setinterval doesn t start, or if you prefer the ajax doesn t trigger. If i take out the hidden / visible part it works !